# Libre writer: Only grey fields instead of page numbers

Tags: libreoffice

Yesterday all was fine, today I opened the document I am working on and the page numbers in the footer are gone, all there is is grey fields without the numbering.

Deleted/recreated the footer, deleted/recreated the page number field, all I get is this bloody grey field.

Inserting other fields like date etc. works.

Please help, thx.

update: 
Still not solved. Exported to .docx and the page numbering works at least as .docx. No idea why.

Comment: Can you switch to another template to see what happens?

Comment: @Jos
Thx for your reply. I am sorry, I don't use templates and I don't really know what exactly templates in libre writer do. All I know is that my page numbering broke without (apparent) reason.

Comment: Well, in that case you use the Standard template, and we want to know if that is messed up. Click Styles/Load Styles... and choose something other than what is already selected. Does anything happen to the page number field?

Comment: @Jos: Ok, I loaded some styles, the page numbering was not affected == still not showing anything but an empty grey field.